# Any way to cache downloads so repeated downloads will instead download from cache?

Tags: windows, vagrant

I use vagrant to create Linux server provision scripts. I often have to run the same `apt-get` commands in the provision script. Some packages I have to download and install are large and take a while on my Internet.

Is it possible to have a software cache of some kind on my Windows machine so when the provision script has to download anything it will first check to see if it's in the cache on my host machine (windows) and if so download from that, or continue to download as normal.

Any advice on how to achieve this? I have slow Internet and sometimes have to run provision scripts multiple times during testing etc.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [vagrant-cachier](https://github.com/fgrehm/vagrant-cachier)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I completely forgot about vagrant plugins tbh.